# Teamcity. How to run tests from specyfic categories only

Tags: nunit, teamcity

My test solution contains few projects, some tests have category and some not. For one environment I need to run just some tests (from diferent projects in solution). The one way I see how to handle it is to mark that tests with some category and run in Teamcity only tests with that category, but I can't configure Teamcity to do that. Can you pleas help me. 
[teamcity screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXy8s.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Additional command line parameters:  --where "cat=~ 'EuroOnly' "